# Martingale not converging a.s.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, martingales

Let $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence of independent random variables with $P(X_n = 2^n) = P(X_n = -2^n) = 1/2.$ Let $M_n := \sum_{k=1}^n X_k$. It was easy to show that $M_n$ is a Martingale, but now I want to prove that $M_n$ does not converge a.s. to a real valued random variable $M$. I tried to disprove convergence in probability or that it is unbounded in probability, but feel like I need some help.

Comment: It's obvious that $M_n$ does not converge (is _surely_ divergent), because $M_{n+1}-M_nn$ does not tend to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\PM}{\mathbb P}$**Hint:**
\begin{align*}
\frac 1 4=\PM(X_n = 2^n , X_{n-1}=2^{n-1}) \leq  \PM(M_n \geq 2^n + 2 )  
\end{align*}
So $M_n$ tends to infinity on a set with strictly positive measure.